# Is there anyway to have various levels for php enumerations?

Tags: php, enumeration

Does anyone know for php AbstractEnumeration if there is any way to do another level underneath it?

so like...

```
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';
```

But I have an optional parameter for a:

```
const a = 'a' => '=123'
```

I know this is probably going to end up as a hash table instead, but just wondering what interesting things I can do with php enums.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support native Enumerations.

You do something like:

```
abstract class ErrorCode
{
   const NOT_FOUND = 404;
   const OK = 200;
   // etc.
```

}

$error = ErrorCode::NOT_FOUND;

This won't work in PHP:

```
const a = 'a' => '=123'
```

Comment: I've been using this: https://github.com/eloquent/enumeration

But I like the latter idea. Thanks! I'll see if it works out.

EDIT: php doesn't allow expressions in constant values

Answer (score 0):

you could serialize the object as an array:

```
# serialize data into an array
define ("a", serialize (array ("a" => 123)));

# use it wherever you want
$a = unserialize (a);
```